# Error Oracle query ORA-00905

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
SELECT to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AS fecha
     , SUM(total) AS total 
FROM (SELECT  FECHA_CREACION AS FECHA, Count(FECHA_CREACION) AS TOTAL
      FROM ROBOT_CONTEO_CONSULTA
      GROUP BY FECHA_CREACION)
WHERE fecha BETWEEN :fechaDesde AND :fechaHasta  
GROUP BY to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

but it gives me this:

> Error message: ORA-00905: missing keyword

But, when I do something like this

```
WHERE fecha BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-20 AND CURRENT_DATE
```

it does work. What is wrong?

I need it with parameters because I will create a view with that.

The full error:

[image: Clic to see]

Comment: is fechaDesde **ALWAYS** lower than fechaHasta?  and why is the group by missing `:ss` where as it's in the select.

Comment: why dont you post the complete error message and the Oracle version?

Comment: Yes, it is and the data always arrives well, I have made a debug

Comment: Should it be `to_date(:fechaDesde, 'Format') and to_date(:fechaHasta,'Format')`?  or is the data already in a date datatype?  Basically could the problem be the implicit conversion of varchar to date data type for the between?

Comment: I tried this too: WHERE fecha BETWEEN TO_DATE(:fechaDesde,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(:fechaHasta, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss')

Comment: Your query exactly as posted will **not** work, because the expression in `select` does not match the one in `group by` - xQbert already pointed that out. Please post your **100% exact** query. Do post the FULL error message: it will point to the exact line of code (and even the position within that line) where the Oracle parser believes it has found a syntactical mistake.

Comment: Yeah, the error is in the between line, i tried WHERE fecha BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE-20 AND CURRENT_DATE  and it work but i need it whith parameters

Comment: What application are you using to communicate with the database? The error message doesn't look familiar; any reasonably good interface should not remove critical information (such as line number) from the error message when it displays it to you. Can you run the same query directly, for example using SQL\*Plus? Also - depending on your interface - is it possible that it doesn't understand `BETWEEN`? You could try `where fecha >= :fechadesde and fecha <= :fechahasta`, if that works you will know that your interface does not support full Oracle SQL.

Comment: I use Hibernate over Java, my Database engine is DBeaver i will try it @mathguy and NativeQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing two things. The query that you are currently calling from your java application and the view that you want to create.

In the query as provided, you indeed need these 2 variables that you will bind in your application with something like `query.setParameter("fechaDesde", myStartDate);`

But you don't need to put these parameters in your view just try the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_TEST_VIEW AS
SELECT to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') AS fecha
     , SUM(total) AS total 
FROM (SELECT  FECHA_CREACION AS FECHA, Count(FECHA_CREACION) AS TOTAL
      FROM ROBOT_CONTEO_CONSULTA
      GROUP BY FECHA_CREACION)
GROUP BY to_char(trunc(fecha,'HH')+(30*round(to_char( trunc(fecha,'MI'),'MI')/30))/1440,'DD/MM/YYYY hh24:mi:ss') 
ORDER BY fecha ASC;
```

And then in your java code you will have something like

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM MY_TEST_VIEW WHERE FETCHA BETWEEN :fechaDesde AND :fechaHasta");
query.setParameter("fechaDesde ", myStartDateVar);
query.setParameter("fechaHasta", myEndDateVar);
```

EDIT : Just be carefull, your `fecha` field is a VARCHAR2 and not a date. You might have weird behaviours if you try to do a between because Oracle will test if the string provided is between 2 other varchars and you will have weird results. it should be a date for it to work properly

Comment: Thank you! This is a different form and it looks great, I'll try it right away.

Comment: That worked, thank you all, this in case someone serves:                                                                     
                                                                            
@Query(value="SELECT FECHA, TOTAL FROM ROBOT_CONSULTAS_BY_HORA_VW WHERE FECHA BETWEEN :fechaDesde AND :fechaHasta", nativeQuery=true)
 List<Object[]> findAllByHour(@Param("fechaDesde") Date fechaDesde,@Param("fechaHasta")  Date fechaHasta);